# unable to validate username and password from DB in jsp login form

Tags: java, jsp

After registration, user will see this form where all the details from registration form are captured into database

```
<html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>JSP Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>Email confirmation has been sent to your email address</h3>
            <a href="http://localhost:6060/JSP_RegistrationAndLoginForm/LoginForm.jsp">click here to login</a>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Login Form:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Login Form</h3>
        <form name="myForm" method="POST" action="ValidateLoginServlet2.do" onSubmit="return validateLogin()">
            User name: <input type="text" name="uname"/> 
            Password: <input type="password" name="pwd"/>
            <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Login validation servlet:

```
public class ValidateLoginServlet2 extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
//        processRequest(request, response);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String username = request.getParameter("uname");
        String password = request.getParameter("pwd");

        try
        {
            Connection con = OracleDBConnection.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select username, password from registration where username =? and password=?");
            statement.setString(1, username);
            statement.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            if(result.next())
            {
                response.sendRedirect("LoginSuccessful.jsp");
            }
            else
            {
                out.println("username and password are incorrect");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
```

I get an DB related error after submitting username and password from the login form saying `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "PASSWORD": invalid identifier`

Comment: Does it print 'username and password are incorrect'? (Should be 'or' BTW). Is there anything in the server log? Exception? Computer exploded? Evidence?

Comment: Try the changes suggested by @SpringLearner

Comment: I get an exception saying `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "PASSWORD": invalid identifier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace these 2 lines

```
statement.setString(13, username);
statement.setString(14, password);
```

with

```
statement.setString(1, username);
statement.setString(2, password);
```

Comment: You are right but I still get an exception saying:` java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "PASSWORD": invalid identifier`

Comment: @kittu,Can you post your table structue and column names?

Comment: Table structure is `firstname, lastname, male, female, mobile, email, address, street, area, state, country, pin, username, password`. All of them are `varchar(200)`

Comment: @kittu as per this article http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00904_string_invalid_identifier.htm column name is either missing or invalid

Comment: You are right. The column name for password was mistyped

Comment: @kittu do delete all comments that are not relevent to this answer